# myasp.net Hosting Database Server Not Found Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have moved my asp.net website built in vs2010 to the web host myasp.net. I am trying to connect to the database, but their default connection string:

```
Data Source=SQL5024.myASP.NET;Initial Catalog=MYDBNAME;User Id=MYUSERNAME;Password=YOUR_DB_PASSWORD
```

does not work. It throws this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

The rest of the error message is as follows:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)] System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +92  System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +285
>          System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover, SqlAuthenticationMethod authType) +372
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +172
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +849
>        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +320   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken) +591
>       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +5699747 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
>          System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +681
>          System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +89
>          System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +426
>          System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
>         System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +191 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +154
>         System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +21
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +90
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +166
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
>          System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +120
>          System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +136
>          System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable) +86 System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +1494
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +278
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.PerformSelect() +37
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +114
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +23
>          System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +88
>          System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
>          System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
>          System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4775

I have tried editing the connection string to include the server and port as follows but it does not seem to make a difference.

```
Server=SQL5024.myASP.NET,1433;
```

I believe the SQL Server version on the website is 2014. I have recreated the database I was using locally to the letter, so I do not understand what the issue is. Am I missing something to do with the instance?

Comment: seems your server name is invalid. Are you sure it should be `SQL5024.myASP.NET` ??

Comment: As S.Akbari said check that the server exists. And you can connect to it.  Seems the server name is wrong.

Comment: SQL5024.myASP.NET isnt accepting any connections, looks like a problem on myASP.NET's side

Comment: so I should try and remote in? the server name was something I added in, but the site does give SQL5024.myASP.NET as the server name, and lists Mircosoft SQL Server 2014 underneath

Comment: _Typically_ hosting providers will give you specific instructions on how to connect to SQL instances _remotely **and** (separately) from within your application_. The error above is explicitly saying you have a connectivity issue (between your application and your sql instance).

Answer (score -1):

It turns out I needed to edit the connection string in the web.config as well as the backend code for that page. Amateur mistake, but maybe this well help someone who has a similar problem.